# Google Play Publisher Payments Deductions

Tags: payment, publisher

I am want to start selling Android Applications on Google Play. I have checked other forums posts, I have found:

1. Google takes 30% of comission. So If I sell my app for $1 => then I would receive $0.7 as revenue.
2. Also noticed Google Checkout also has some fees on per transaction and monthly volume basis, i.e., $0.30 + 2.9% of amount

I want to know is Google Checkout transactions will also be deducted in addition to 30% commission by Google or is it the same.

I want to keep my application real cheap (counting on bulk selling)

Can Any of you please advise what is the deal with it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cannical Sells theres for 20% I imagine the Uphone will be similar http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/commercial-software-faqs/

Comment: http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/11/take-that-facebook-google-commission-on-game-transactions-is-5-percent-not-30-percent/